# Error in Accessing Multiset element C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, set, multiset

I get the error

```
../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-socket-impl.cc: In member function ‘void ns3::MpTcpSocketImpl::OpenCWND(uint8_t, uint32_t)’:
../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-socket-impl.cc:2471: error: no match for ‘operator-’ in ‘sFlow->ns3::MpTcpSubFlow::measuredRTT.std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::end [with _Key = double, _Compare = std::less<double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<double>]() - 1’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_bvector.h:179: note: candidates are: ptrdiff_t std::operator-(const std::_Bit_iterator_base&, const std::_Bit_iterator_base&)
```

because I tried:

```
  double maxrttval = *(sFlow->measuredRTT.end() - 1);
```

now, in the same code  `double baserttval = *(sFlow->measuredRTT.begin());`
works perfectly well.

I can't understand what is wrong  . I have to access the last element just like I accessed the first element. Thanks for help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator category of [multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) is [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which does not support `operator+` nor `operator-`, they're only supported by [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). But it supports `operator--`, so you can:

```
double maxrttval = *(sFlow->measuredRTT.end()--);
```

And you can get the last element by reverse iterator too:

```
double maxrttval = *(sFlow->measuredRTT.rbegin());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the last item of the multiset use [std::multiset::rbegin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/rbegin/):

> Return reverse iterator to reverse beginning Returns a reverse
>   iterator pointing to the last element in the container (i.e., its
>   reverse beginning).
>
> Reverse iterators iterate backwards: increasing them moves them
>   towards the beginning of the container.
>
> rbegin points to the element preceding the one that would be pointed
>   to by member end.

So use

```
double maxrttval = *(sFlow->measuredRTT.rbegin());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use std::advance?

```
it = sFlow->measuredRTT.end();
std::advance(it, -1);
double maxrttval = *it;
```